# Truecrypt + Windows 7 100MB partition corrupt

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, truecrypt

I've got a problem.  I have a new SSD where I installed W7 Ultimate. However my other drive (HDD) had W7 Ultimate with Truecrypt (Entire System Drive). Sadly the first 100MB of this disk has now become corrupt. When I start truecrypt and type in my password, I get: "Error: No bootable partition found.". When I hit ESC I get a windows error screen which says: "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible" `0xC000000E`.

When I start W7 from my SSD I can see the drive in Windows Explorer. Strangely I can still mount the system partition with Truecrypt and browse the files so luckily I can still recover all of my data. The 100MB partition however is now partially browseable from W7 which should not be the case.

Is there a way to fix this first 100MB? I don't want to decrypt everything since the drive is 1TB and almost completely filled.  I tried the Truecrypt Rescue Disk and selected option 2 & 3 but that didn't seem to work

---

Ok I'm still having the same problem but now I'm trying to copy all the files to another disk but I'm having problems with hiberfil.sys and some other windows exclusive folders like 'Documents and Settings'.

How can I clone this file to the other drive?

Answer (score 0):

All spinning disk repairs usually begin with [SpinRite](http://www.grc.com/sr/spinrite.htm). This does a sector by sector repair attempt of bad/corrupt sectors and is a staple of magnetic drive repair.

To clone your disk, there are a number of tools out there like Clonezilla and Easeus Disk Copy. Just do a Google search and you'll have lots of options.

Hope this helps