# Truecrypt + Windows 7 100MB partition corrupt

Tags: windows, windows-7, partitioning, truecrypt

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Truecrypt + Windows 7 100MB partition corrupt](https://superuser.com/questions/272000/truecrypt-windows-7-100mb-partition-corrupt)

Hi,

I've got a problem. I have a new SSD where I installed W7 Ultimate. However my other drive (HDD) had W7 Ultimate with Truecrypt (Entire System Drive). Sadly the first 100MB of this disk has now become corrupt. When I start truecrypt and type in my password, I get: "Error: No bootable partition found.". When I hit ESC i get a windows error screen which says: "The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible" 0xC000000E.

When I start W7 from my SSD I can see the drive in Windows Explorer. Strangely I can still mount the system partition with Truecrypt and browse the files so luckily I can still recover all of my data. The 100MB partition however is now partially browseable from W7 which should not be the case.

Is there a way to fix this first 100MB? I don't want to decrypt everything since the drive is 1TB and almost completely filled. I tried the Truecrypt Rescue Disk and selected option 2 & 3 but that didn't seem to work :(